# Passing SAFEARRAY value to COM client

Tags: python-3.x, com, win32com, safearray

I am trying to Automate a Tool via win32com.client module which expects the Input to be in the following format,The format shown below if specific to MATLAB.

```
HRESULT StaticStokesParameters([in] SAFEARRAY(double) newVal)
```

I have no clue what does SAFEARRAY type represent. I have tried to create an 2D array in python, but i keep receiving the following error,

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)
```

I can read the values out without any problem, but when i assign the same value back as SET argument, then it fails to do so,

```
EngineMgr = win32com.client.Dispatch("EngineMgr")
Engine = EngineMgr.OpenEngine(0)
d_array = Engine.StaticStokesParameters
print(d_array)
**(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0) # Output of Print Statement**
Engine.StaticStokesParameters = d_array
**Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#17>", line 1, in <module>
Engine.StaticStokesParameters = d_array
File "C:\Users\ashes\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 549, in __setattr__
self._oleobj_.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352571, 'Type mismatch.', None, 1)**
```

Comment: SAFEARRAY are a sort of COM array. win32com should support SAFEARRAYs natively, google on "SAFEARRAY win32com python"

Comment: @SimonMourier I tried that (for a similar issue).  Does not seem to work.  Do SAFEARRAYS have to be built up using CTYPES?

Comment: The answer below constructs a SAFEARRAY using pywin32, if it doesn't suit your need, you should ask another question

Comment: @SimonMourier I did post a similar question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75769241/how-do-you-format-a-list-of-python-values-to-be-compatible-with-the-com-safearra

Answer (score 0):

Got this working by importing below shown modules,

```
from win32com.client import VARIANT
import pythoncom

sop= Engine.StaticStokesParameters
Engine.StaticStokesParameters = VARIANT(pythoncom.VT_ARRAY | pythoncom.VT_R8,sop)
```